# Reading shibboleth attributes in session page

Tags: asp.net, shibboleth

I'm successfully logging into my Service Provider test page with Shibboleth. I then go to the /Shibboleth.sso/Session page and I can see all the values that I need. I wrote a classic ASP page which dumps all the server Variables[request.serverVariables("HTTP_VARIABLE")], but I cannot see the values that I want to access. 
My question is How can I access my attributes to see them on the page where I am dumping the server variables.

```
<Attribute id="iMIS_Login" name="http://exp.org/iMIS/Profile/Login"/>
<Attribute id="iMIS_ID" name="http://exp.org/iMIS/Profile/ID"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess#NativeSPAttributeAccess-EnvironmentVariables)

> When using headers, the main difference is that instead of using the names defined via the mapping process, the application must prefix them with "HTTP_", and in most tools upcase the rest of the name as well.

and as described in [this thread](https://shibboleth.net/pipermail/users/2011-November/001635.html)

you can get the value with `request.serverVariables('HTTP_IMIS_LOGIN')` and `request.serverVariables('HTTP_IMIS_ID')`